# Summary of changes between two commits of branches in Git

Tags: git

What command can I use to know how many files are different between two branches, just a summary, not the actual files. Something like:

```
51 Modified
 3 Deleted
 4 New files
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `git diff --stat`. And there's the even shorter `--shortstat`.

e.g. on branch `master` type `git diff --stat otherbranchname`

Comment: also, `git diff --stat commitFrom commitTo`

Answer (score 6):

```
git diff --shortstat branch1..branch2
```

This will show the differences between `branch1` and `branch2` but only output a short summary, for example:

```
2 files changed, 165 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

There are other ways to specify the commit range, `git diff` will look at, you can read about them [in the manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).